# How to run Mobx validation for field only when field exists

Tags: reactjs, mobx

The fields are defined as follows

```
fields: [
        {
          name: "workflowTypeId",
          bindings: "TextField",
        },
        {
          name: "height",
          label: "Height",
          bindings: "TextField",
          rules: "required",
        },
        {
          name: "width",
          label: "Width",
          bindings: "TextField",
          rules: "required",
        }]
```

Height field is displayed conditionally based on the value of workflowTypeId.

**The issue is that even if height field is not present in the UI, validation for height still runs and prevents form submission.**

How to run the validation only when the field exists in the UI?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I am using Mobx react form(https://github.com/foxhound87/mobx-react-form)

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain what library you are using at least. And add it to the tags

Comment: @Danila i am using mobx react form